# Not accepting login from bcrypt password

Tags: laravel, authentication, passwords, bcrypt

after reset password I cannot login use my password

```
public function resetPassword(Request $request){
    $info = $request->all();

    $validator = Validator::make($info, [
        'id' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){ 

        return ['res'=>'0', 'data' => 'parameters error'];

    }else{    
        $new_password = bcrypt(request("password"));

        $user = User::find(request("id"));
        $user -> password = $new_password;
        $user -> pass_reset = 0;
        $user-> save();

        $passwordRecord = new Password_record; 
        $passwordRecord -> user_id = $user->id; 
        $passwordRecord -> password = $new_password;
        $passwordRecord -> created_at = time();
        $passwordRecord-> active_flag = 1;
        $passwordRecord->save();

        return ['res'=>'1', 'data' => $new_password];
    }
}
```

this password successfuly saved in a db.

this is what I mentioned in my login function,

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials1 = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $new_password =  bcrypt($credentials1["password"]); 
    $credentials = ['username' => $credentials1["email"], 'password' => $new_password]; 

    $user = User::where('username',$credentials["username"])->where('password',$new_password)->first();
}
```

bcrypt one always changed in  tie to time , I couldn't find better way to do this! can anyone tell me what I did  wrong? Or do I need another way to make this login works ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: ```"laravel/framework": "5.5.*"```

Comment: Is this a custom login system means you have prepared ?

Comment: yes, not default one

Comment: you can't login now or you want some other things to do ?

Comment: I cannot login because of password.

Comment: can you show the password reset code ?

Comment: I have updated into my Question, you can check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to make it in this way

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    if (Auth::attempt ( array ('username' => $request->get ( 'username' ),'password' =>$request->get ( 'password' ) ) )) {

        return Auth::user();
               OR
        return Redirect::route('home');

    } else {
        Session::flash ( 'message', "Invalid Credentials , Please try again." );
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Hash::make()` method to encrypt your password:

```
$new_password = Hash::make($credentials1["password"]);
```

Comment: this is for login function right!
but given wrong db value

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the below code and the whole request.

```
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the issue was that the password column was named `password_hash` instead of `password`.
Renaming the column to `password` fixed the issue.